# Problema con estilo en caja de texto

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con la parte de estilo en un textbox para ingresar una clave con el tipo de clave
Al ingresar textmode="password" en el textbox de clave me quita el estilo y me lo deja como predeterminado
Hay manera de que esto no pase la idea es  no quitar el estilo de este textbox
Este es el codigo

```
input[type=text], [type=txtPassword] {
width: 80%;
height: 13%;
font: 16px normal normal uppercase helvetica,arial,serif;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 0;
right: 20px;
```

}

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" placeholder="  Password" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Por que me parece tienes mal identificado el selector en tu regla CSS, es decir para poder leer tanto el `input` de tipo texto como el `input` de tipo contraseña o password la sintaxis debe ser la siguiente:

```
nodoDOM[atributo="tipo"], [atributo="tipo"]
```

Y si observas lo que tienes en el `type` es el `id` que le asignaste a dicha caja de texto lo cual para lo que estás tratando de lograr es claramente incorrecto y debería quedar así:

```
input[type="text"], [type="password"]
```

Código completo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        input[type="text"], [type="password"] {
          width: 80%;
          height: 13%;
          font: 16px normal normal uppercase helvetica,arial,serif;
          border-radius: 10px;
          border: 0;
          right: 20px;
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="password">Password
    </body>
    </html>
```

- Recomiendo leas [aquí sobre los **selectores de atributo**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Si funciono muchas gracias no sabia que se realizaba el código de esa manera  gracias por algo nuevo.

Comment: Me parece de risa que hayas rechazado la edición de la respuesta. Te sugiero que la modifiques con un análisis básico de los errores gramaticales, indentación y Markdown.